# Selecting multiple files on Excel using the FileDialog

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add multiple files when opening My Documents. I currently have a command button and when clicked the file dialog window is opened.

I am able to select as many as I can, however when it is emailed to the address it only shows 2 attachments, the first one being the form on the spreadsheet and the second being the file chosen from the file dialog window.

How can I add more than 2 attachments to my email?

I've tried using a For Loop, so there can be many attachments, however this is not working.

Please see below.

```
Sub SbExtra_Attachment()
'mssgbox do you have another attachment to add ?
Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Do you have any other attachments? 'Yes' or 'No'.", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

    If Response = vbYes Then

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

            If fd.Show = -1 Then
                For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
                StrFile = fd.SelectedItems(i)
                Next i

            End If

        Else

    End If

End Sub
```

The above currently only attaches a maximum of 2 files.

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm adding the attachments to an email.

Comment: Maybe `StrFile = StrFile & ", " & fd.SelectedItems(i)`.  Because `StrFile`  will always be overwritten in the loop instead of stacking them up.  Not sure if that comma is the right delimiter, but I think it would work.

Comment: You keep replacing the value in the StrFile string. You do nothing else in the loop but change that value. When the loop finishes, your variable only holds the last file's path in the string. How are you actually adding the attachments?

Comment: Thanks n8. I will give it a try.

Comment: Vacip, when clicking the command button on the spreadsheet it sends it using the OutMail which is under a different module

Answer (score 1):

Going ahead and making this an answer because I am confident!

Maybe `StrFile = StrFile & ", " & fd.SelectedItems(i)`. Because `StrFile` will always be overwritten in the loop instead of stacking them up. Not sure if that comma is the right delimiter, but I think it would work

**Edit**

It looks like file pickers don't delimit by comma, it puts them in quotes.  So you probably need it to be `StrFile = """" & StrFile & """ """ & fd.SelectedItems(i) & """"`.  This code will include a leading `""` though, if the StrFile is not empty beforehand, so you would have to drop the leading 3 characters if this is the case with `If Left(StrFile, 3) = """"" " Then StrFile = Right(StrFile, len(StrFile) - 3)` after the loop is done.

Comment: Hi N8. Thanks for that, however it is not working. The code above only attaches the form itself now.

Comment: It attaches the form to the form?  I assume the file picker opens to a list of potential attachments, yes?

Comment: Oh I get it.  So, what is StrFile?  It's not a String, (which is what Str typically stands for, so you're using confusing naming conventions) normally a type is declared.

Comment: It is declared publicly as a String on a different module

Comment: If I used a message box for the code you showed above, it does indeed show all the files I have selected. However when it sends it to the email address it only shows the form and one file I had chosen from the directory.

Comment: I went and looked at how the file picker works.  When you select multiple items it wraps them in quotes.